# How to assign the regression coefficients of a factor variable to a new variable according to factor levels?

Tags: r, stata

I am a newbie to R. After I ran a linear regression with categorical variable "sale year"

```
ols <- lm(logprice = x + factor(city) + factor(sale_year))
```

I would like to create a new variable, which tells me for each observation the regression coefficient of factor(sale_year) on the sale_year of that observation.

```
     sale_year            new variable
     1980     coef(ols)["factor(sale_year)1980"]
     1973     coef(ols)["factor(sale_year)1973"]
     1990     coef(ols)["factor(sale_year)1990"]
     1990     coef(ols)["factor(sale_year)1990"]
     1973     coef(ols)["factor(sale_year)1973"]

      ...
```

If there is no other factor variables, then I can simply set all variables to zero except for sale_year, and use `predict.lm` to get the coefficients. But given multiple factor variables, it's messier, and I cannot get it right in R.

In Stata, I can do this:

> ```
> xi: reg logprice x i.city i.sale_year 
> gen newvar = .
> levelsof sale_year, local(saleyr)
> foreach lv of local saleyr {
>     replace newvar = _b[_Isaleyr`lv'] if sale_year == `lv'
> }
> ```

How can I do this in R? Thanks!

Comment: The Stata code here is incorrect and more importantly largely pointless. `_b()` needs to be `_b[]`. That fixed, the lasting effect of the code might be that the variable `newvar` contains repeated copies of the _last_ slope coefficient calculated. Your Stata example is thus obscure without a complete and legal segment of code.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for pointing out the _b[] error. The above stata code actually worked in my case. I have it tested...

Comment: `log(price)` worked? My major point remains: your `foreach` loop just overwrites repeatedly.

Comment: @NickCox, I forgot to add if sale_year == `lv'. I did this in Stata some time ago...

Comment: Thanks on behalf of those reading the Stata code for the code fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't supply the sample data, I will use iris data from R:

```
mydata<-iris
mydata$Petal.Width<-as.factor(mydata$Petal.Width)
str(mydata)
 str(mydata)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : Factor w/ 22 levels "0.1","0.2","0.3",..: 2 2 2 2 2 4 3 2 2 1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
myreg<-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Width+Species,data=mydata)
k<-length(levels(mydata$Petal.Width))
mycoef<-coef(myreg)[3:(k+1)]
mycoef<-data.frame(mycoef)
> head((mycoef)
                   mycoef
Petal.Width0.2 0.13981323
Petal.Width0.3 0.17193663
Petal.Width0.4 0.20220902
Petal.Width0.5 0.31915175
Petal.Width0.6 0.08864592

mycoef$var<-rownames(mycoef)
rownames(mycoef)<-1:dim(mycoef)[1]
mycoef[,c("var","mycoef")]



mycoef[,c("var","mycoef")]
              var     mycoef
1  Petal.Width0.2 0.13981323
2  Petal.Width0.3 0.17193663
3  Petal.Width0.4 0.20220902
4  Petal.Width0.5 0.31915175
```

Update:

```
mycoef$var1<-substring(mycoef$var,12,15)
myout<-merge(mydata1,mycoeff,by.x="Petal.Width",by.y="var1")
> head(myout)
  Petal.Width Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Species            var    mycoef
1         0.2          4.9         3.0          1.4  setosa Petal.Width0.2 0.1398132
2         0.2          4.7         3.2          1.3  setosa Petal.Width0.2 0.1398132
3         0.2          4.6         3.1          1.5  setosa Petal.Width0.2 0.1398132
4         0.2          5.0         3.6          1.4  setosa Petal.Width0.2 0.1398132
5         0.2          5.1         3.5          1.4  setosa Petal.Width0.2 0.1398132
6         0.2          5.4         3.7          1.5  setosa Petal.Width0.2 0.1398132
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in my question. Actually I need a new column of the same length as my regression sample data. In other words, for any observation/row of the sample data, I know the level of the factor variable of interest for that observation, and then I want to know what's the regression coefficient on that factor level.

Comment: Please see the updates. You can just use `merge` if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to use `predict.lm` to get the baseline value for the first level of the factor, since there will be no coefficient for that level (or rather it will be 0). All the other coefficients are really offsets to that value (assuming that the result of predict is what you are expecting), so something like:

```
  faclev1 <- predict(old, list(x=mean(x), city=levels(city)[1], sale_year =levels(sale_year)[1])
  otherlevs <- faclev1 + coef(ols)[grep("sale_year", names(coef(ols) ) )]
```

For a vector of coefficients matching individual cases:

```
 fac_coef <- c(0, coef(ols)[grep("sale_year", names(coef(ols) ) )]
 fac_coef[ as.numeric(sale_year) ]
```

This works because the order of levels is the same as the order in which the coefficients get displayed and the numeric value is what determines how levels ordinarily get displayed.

Comment: That works when I want the whole set of coefficients on factor variable. What if I need to know for any observation/row, the corresponding reg coefficient on the sale year of that observation? In other words, I need a new column of the same length as the original regression sample.